# JPA foreign key NOT AS OBJECT

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two simple tables in MySQL

```
User ---(one-to-many)--- Expense
```

I am using Spring JPA to generate theses two entities. Expense has 'user_id' foreign key field which references 'id' field in User table.

I use JSON in requests to populate tables

```
User
{"id":1, "username":"user"}

Expense
{
 "id":1, 
 "user_id":1,        <--- this value is not null in MySQL
 "expense":"expense"
}
```

When calling API I already have **user_id** value and I don't want to pass the whole object.

Is there a way to tell Spring that this is INTEGER FOREIGN KEY that references 'id' column in 'User' table?

All the examples I found online only showed how to achieve by passing whole 'User' object in the JSON.

My current implementation:

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    private String username; 
}

@Entity
public class Car{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user_id;

    private String expense;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this issue:
You could map the user_id column like this:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Expense {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
  private Integer userId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private User user;

  private String expense;
}
```

if you're only **ever** going to save expenses with the user_id like such:

```java
@Test
void saveExpense_withUserId_expenseSaved() {
    Expense expense = new Expense();
    expense.setUserId(1);

    assertTrue(expenseRepository.save(expense).getId() != null);
}
```

**Be very careful ! This will cause user_id to be null if you're trying to save Expense by setting the User object**

```java
@Test
void saveExpense_withUser_throwsNullUserId() {
    User testUser = userRepository.findById(1).orElseThrow();

    Expense expense = new Expense();
    expense.setUser(testUser);

    assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class, () -> expenseRepository.save(expense));
}
```

A cleaner way is to only map the relation and get a reference to the User object when persisting the reference:

```java
@Entity
public class Expense {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
  private User user;

  private String expense;
}
```

```java
@Test
void saveExpense_withUserReference_expenseSaved() {
    Expense expense = new Expense();
    expense.setUser(userRepository.getById(1));
    
    assertTrue(expenseRepository.save(expense).getId() != null);
}
```

The reference you get with `getById` does not generate a SELECT query and is therefore very efficient unlike `findById`.
*NOTE*: You could compare the two codes by switching commits with [this code](https://github.com/lookslikeitsnot/stackoverflow-46145233/tree/main/question)

Answer (score 0):

You should not transport JPA entities in the requests.

Create POJOS with the necessary IDs for the function you want to perform and map the java entities in the services layer.

For queries for example, you will only have to instantiate the entity and set the ID, and if you need more fields you can do a find () by id and through a direct access to the object get the rest of properties

Answer (score 0):

Why you involve `Car` entity?

To me this is simple:

```java
@Entity
@Table(xxxx)
public class Expense implements Serializable {
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
      private User user;
}
```

Is enough. JPA knows that it's a FK and will search the ID column in `User`.